# How can I know which are my most used aliases?

Tags: zsh, vim, alias

I would like to know which aliases I use most often, in both zsh and vim, so I can rename them to have more or fewer letters depending on the use. And also to remove aliases I never use, because I feel like I have too many.

Comment: Vim has aliases?

Comment: The leader mappings.

Comment: You could always declare 'alias bankruptcy' - comment them all out and see which ones you miss, and uncomment/rename them as you go.

Answer (score 2):

This command will show the most used commands:

```
sort ~/.zsh_history | uniq -c | sort -n | tail
```

You could use `tail -50` to see the top 50 commands. By default it's limited to 10.

As to which ones are not used, please create a new question. This is a whole different problem.